# how to make the sliding drawer button invisible-android

Tags: android, slideshow

I'm trying to make the handle button of the sliding drawer invisible or to disable it when I click on it because I want to call it by another button not with the handle button

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/open_setting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
 <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handlee" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handlee"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
```

This is the code of the other button that I used to open this slide.

```
Button openslide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open_setting);
    final SlidingDrawer setting = (SlidingDrawer)   
             findViewById(R.id.setting_Slide);
openslide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setting.open();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do yo want disable button on ActionBar?

Comment: want to disable the @+id/handlee button

Comment: Do you try set openslide.setEnable(false)?

Comment: no i ill try it if it works i ill let you know

Comment: openslide.setEnable(false); not working